# How to loop through JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to loop through currencies from fixer.io API, 
but my code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    $json = file_get_contents('http://api.fixer.io/latest');
    $data = json_decode($json);
    dd($data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            dump($value[$i]);
        }
        die;
    }
```

Edit: var_dump($data);

[image]

Comment: Please be little more specific, tell us *what is not working*, *what is the expected output* etc. Also, what does `dd()` function do?

Comment: Can you shed more light on your code.  Why do you have to loop twice? `var_dump()` the json data you received from the API, and share the structure here

Comment: @RajdeepPaul dd($data); dumps & die, i am expecting EUR, USD etc.

Comment: @OniyaDaniel Check edited post

Comment: use true as a second parameter for json_decode() method. that will return array instead of php standard object

Comment: @Stackingcoder I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, pass second argument as `true` in the [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to get the decoded data as an array. Then, use a simple `foreach` loop like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.fixer.io/latest');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($data['rates'] as $currency => $value){
    echo $currency . " => " . $value . '<br />';
}
```